# How to pickle a scipy.stats distribution (can't pickle instancemethod objects)

Tags: python, scipy, pickle

How can I save a scipy.stats distribution?

For example:

```
a = [scipy.stats.norm(0,1), scipy.stats.norm(0,2)]
with open("distro.pickle", 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(a, f)
```

Doing this I get a `TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do not support pickling. The easier way to "solve" your problem is to pickle the arguments and, when unpickling, create a new object:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Norm = namedtuple('Norm', 'mu variance')
>>> def pickle_norm(n):
...     return pickle.dumps(Norm(*n.args))
... 
>>> def unpickle_norm(s):
...     return scipy.stats.norm(*pickle.loads(s))
... 
>>> s = pickle_norm(scipy.stats.norm(5, 10))
>>> d = unpickle_norm(s)
```

Comment: I think that's the best way to go. A useful extension would be to also pickle the name so it works automatically for all distributions. I didn't try how this could be made to work.