# How to remove instancemethod objects, for the sake of pickle, without modifying the original class

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I want to persistantly hold on to an object from `reverend.thomas.Bayes`. Of course, if I try to pickle one of these classes directly, I get:

```
TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

To work around this, I have tried declaring two functions:

```
import types
from itertools import chain
from copy import copy
from reverend.thomas import Bayes

def prepare_bayes_for_pickle(bayes_obj):
    dic = copy(bayes_obj.__dict__) #I also tried using deepcopy instead of copy
    for k in dic:
        if type(k) == types.MethodType:
            dic.pop(k)
    return dic

def reconstruct_bayes_from_pickle(bayes_dic):
    b = Bayes()
    # Merge b with bayes_dic, with bayes_dic taking precedence
    dic = dict(chain(bayes_dic, b))
    b.__dict__ = dic
    return b
```

Basically, I try copying the object's `__dict__`, and try to remove `instancemethod`s by testing the type against `types.MethodType`.

I then would reconstruct the object by creating a new `Bayes` object and then merging it back together with `bayes_dic` (after it is UnPickled.)

But, I haven't gotten up to the second method yet, because I still can't pickle the object that is returned from `prepare_bayes_for_pickle` without getting the original error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pickle a scipy.stats distribution (can't pickle instancemethod objects)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235693/how-to-pickle-a-scipy-stats-distribution-cant-pickle-instancemethod-objects)

Comment: However, the answer to the supposed duplicate involves only pickling the arguments to the object. I don't think that would work for me because I will be mutating this object a lot: unpickling all the mutation arguments and creating a new object each time would mean the calculations would have to be repeated every time the object is "unpickled."

Comment: Did you take into account that pickling/unpickling to file takes a huge amount of time compared to almost any other operation? I mean, it is possible that even repeating the computation would not be the bottleneck. You should profile before making such statements. Also, most importantly, I saw that the `Bayes` class has a `save` and `load` methods. Why aren't you using them?

Answer (score 2):

The better solution would be for you to add a `__getstate__` method onto the `Bayes` class (with accompanying `__setstate__`):

```
import types
from reverend.thomas import Bayes

def Bayes__getstate__(self):
    state = {}
    for attr, value in self.__dict__.iteritems():
        if not isinstance(value, types.MethodType):
            state[attr] = value
        elif attr == 'combiner' and value.__name__ == 'robinson':
            # by default, self.combiner is set to self.robinson
            state['combiner'] = None
    return state

def Bayes__setstate__(self, state):
    self.__dict__.update(state)
    # support the default combiner (an instance method):
    if 'combiner' in state and state['combiner'] is None:
        self.combiner = self.robinson

Bayes.__getstate__ = Bayes__getstate__
Bayes.__setstate__ = Bayes__setstate__
```

Now the `Bayes` class can always be pickled and unpickled without additional processing.

I do see that the class has a `self.cache = {}` mapping; perhaps that should be excluded when pickling? Ignore it in `__getstate__` and call `self.buildCache()` in `__setstate__` if that is the case.

Comment: This seems to work for pickling, but going for unpickling, I get `AttributeError: 'Bayes' object has no attribute '_tokenizer'`. Trying `type(bayes_obj._tokenizer)` in the repl (while using a `bayes_obj` that was created without unpickling), returns `<type 'instance'>`.

Comment: @user1436026: I took another look into the object; the instance method is the combiner set to `self.robinson`, I presume. Can you use http://pastie.org to show the *full* traceback of that exception? The default is to set `_tokenizer` to a `reverend.thomas.Tokenizer` instance, which should be picklable.

Comment: @user1436026: Right, so the restored object has no `_tokenizer` attribute, which is strange, since there is nothing in the `__getstate__` to prevent it from being pickled. What does `bayes_obj.__getstate__()` return when called on a 'working' object? Does it include a `_tokenizer` key?

Answer (score 0):

`k` is a key i.e. the attribute/method name.  You need to test the attribute itself:

```
    if type(dic[k]) == types.MethodType:
            ^~~~~~ here
```

I'd prefer using a comprehension; you should also be using `isinstance`:

```
dic = dict((k, v) for k, v in bayes_obj.__dict__
           if not isinstance(v, types.MethodType))
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like getting a square peg to fit a round hole. How about using pickle to pickle the arguments, and unpickle to reconstruct the `reverand.Thomas.Bayes` object?

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> ArgList = namedtuple('your', 'arguments', 'for', 'the', 'reverand')
>>> def pickle_rtb(n):
...     return pickle.dumps(ArgList(*n.args))
... 
>>> def unpickle_rtb(s):
...     return reverand.Thomas.Bayes(*pickle.loads(s))
... 
>>> s = pickle_rtb(reverand.Thomas.Bayes(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) # note arguments are a guess
>>> rtb = unpickle_norm(s)
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235693/how-to-pickle-a-scipy-stats-distribution-cant-pickle-instancemethod-objects) SO question.