# Can't pickle Bayes objects from the reverend module

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, bayesian

I am trying to pickle a Bayes class object. My code is:

```
file = open('Bayes.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(bayes, file)
file.close()
```

I get the following error as

> TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod object

To overcome this, I referred this StackOverflow solution:
    [How to remove instancemethod objects, for the sake of pickle, without modifying the original class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499170/how-to-remove-instancemethod-objects-for-the-sake-of-pickle-without-modifying)

This states to use the methods **getstate**() and **setstate**(). This worked and I was able to pickle my files. 
However, when I try to test my data, I get the error as follows:

```
 File "/home/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reverend/thomas.py", line 254, in guess
 res[pname]=self.combiner(p, pname)
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

My code is as follows:

```
    my_str = ' '
    for val in sourceCode:
        my_str += str(val)
    results = classifier.guess(my_str)
    print results
```

Type of my_str is string. however, it is still not guessing.

Comment: Updated your Question with the code of `getstate()` and `setstate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your class has its own pickling/unpickling support via `bayes.save('bayes.pkl')` and `bayes.load('bayes.pkl')`. It does the following:

```
def save(self, fname='bayesdata.dat'):
    from cPickle import dump
    fp = open(fname, 'wb')
    dump(self.pools, fp)
    fp.close()

def load(self, fname='bayesdata.dat'):
    from cPickle import load
    fp = open(fname, 'rb')
    self.pools = load(fp)
    fp.close()
    self.corpus = self.pools['__Corpus__']
    self.dirty = True
```